# .NET Core MVC 6 misleading IntelliSense

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

While trying to build a web app using .NET Core, I used the Web App template and while everything works exactly as one would expect, the IntelliSense on `.cshtml` pages is extremely misleading. It doesn't recognize `@ViewData`, `@model`, or `@Model` tags, but when a view model is added or a ViewData message is used, the project compiles and runs as normal. However, IntelliSense marks them red like so...

[image]

... and says "Cannot resolve symbol" even when using Microsoft's own .NET Core web application template in a fully updated Visual Studio 2015, will all necessary NuGet packages installed. Does anyone know if this is a bug that needs to be fixed or there's a definitive checklist of NuGet packages to add? Adding various Mvc.Tooling and Tooling.Razer packages only enables tag helpers, but anything other than code after an `@` on a `.cshtml` file is still flagged as an error...

[SOLVED] Please see answer...

Comment: I do not have this issue, therefore it's something different on our machines. I'm running Visual Studio Community 2015, Update 3.

Comment: Same here, VS Community 2015 Update 3, version 14.0.25425.01. Even reinstalled .NET Core Tools to be 100% sure.

Comment: Here's my package.json: https://gist.github.com/mariocatch/62894e82fc73aa377da49053f5f22da3

Comment: Thank you for posting that. Our package.json files are very different, but I basically nuked every bit of cached data and reset everything form scratch. Somehow that solved the problem... But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

After deleting everything from C:\Users[me]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio and VSCommon, then running `devenv /resetuserdata` in the Visual Studio Command Prompt, singing back in, and restoring my environment, the issue resolved itself.

Still not sure whats wrong, but it seems too complex to me to figure out on my own without deeper knowledge of VS 2015...